# How to convert cable TV channel into Ip based stream

Tags: html, streaming, television, decoder, iptv

I already search on internet but not get a proper idea about converting normal analog TV channels into IP based channels. 
Basically i am looking this information to create a application from where i can watch normal cable TV channel inside my custom application. For this i need to convert these channels into IP based stream which my application used play using vlc player API/html5 video tags.
Can someone have idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want have own streaming application,  use open source like [DVBLAST](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJv_qfhejRAhUsP5oKHUDIDTIQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.videolan.org%2Fprojects%2Fdvblast.html&usg=AFQjCNFcoyNWbpcgLijSJ-RnHOwONDO1xA&sig2=nWzcAGh0hmSIAwsqd7La3w) (Of course initial commit on their repository have simplest code as last commit :) ). I do something like you want as i say, and change the code as i want.

But i suggest you that use last version of software like [DVBLAST](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJv_qfhejRAhUsP5oKHUDIDTIQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.videolan.org%2Fprojects%2Fdvblast.html&usg=AFQjCNFcoyNWbpcgLijSJ-RnHOwONDO1xA&sig2=nWzcAGh0hmSIAwsqd7La3w) or [MUMUDVB](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj3i6D4hejRAhXIApoKHZY-Dk8QFggZMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmumudvb.net%2F&usg=AFQjCNH8kmDI-4PGWfL44GGJHXlr0CQNag&sig2=J_oJahRc1IzcJll6wNl_SQ&bvm=bv.145822982,d.bGs), That application is too stable and easy to use, They cover all of routine request, I have a server that run `DVBLAST` on that and it start from 3 years ago..and dont have any problem. `DVBLAST` have a opensource control panel that you can control start or stop the process from other computer in network.

Comment: ok sounds interesting.. How you take input of the stream as analog ?

Comment: Plz read the code in initial commit of dvblast, in dvb.h file

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a free, non-encrypted cable source and the content owners are happy to allow this use case, then you can't legally and technically you will find it very hard also.

If you do have the entitlements, for example you are an IPTV provider with rights to re-distribute content you receive via cable or satellite, then you generally would use a specialist gateway to convert between the DVB transport format and IP, a QAM to IP converter.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this detail. Well yes i have a rights and this app would not be use commercially but just for home test. Can you tell me what kind of hardware/software do i need to convert cable channels into IP